# Why does the strike through comes there in program

Tags: selenium, pycharm

[Whenever start adding xpth it gets strikethrough](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B8fan.png)

Comment: It's driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"") with an import of By now. It's been depreciated for a while

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

`find_elemenet_by_xpath` is depricated that's what you get strike in the app
instead you can Use `By`

```py
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
...
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "").click()
```